# trying to create a Discord webhook, with the avatar and username assigned inside the code

Tags: python, discord, discord.js, webhooks

I am trying to create a Discord webhook, with the avatar and username assigned inside the code.

This is the code I have so far. I have no idea what comes before or after this.

```
{
  "username": "Webhook",
  "avatar_url": "https://i.imgur.com/4M34hi2.png",
  "content": "Text message. Up to 2000 characters.",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you instead [create the webhook from Discord's GUI](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks) (see "Making A Webhook" section)?

If you need to do it programmatically, can you confirm you're sending a POST request to `/channels/{channel.id}/webhooks` and have the `MANAGE_WEBHOOKS` role, per the [webhook resource](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook)? That doc also only shows `name` and `avatar` as fields for a create webhook request.